# Is me = this in JavaScript a good practice to support minification?

Tags: javascript, minify

So in my JavaScript codebase I have been using the `var me = this` idiom to support minification. But I've started questioning this lately, and I was wonder if assignment of `this` to a variable could be avoided with smarter minification tools?

It seems like a tool should be able to detect functions where creating a variable to represent `this` would save characters over multiple calls to `this`. The same could be done for boolean values, like `var yes = true, nope = false`.

Are there tools I could use to avoid setting `var me = this` all over my code base? In general is a good idea to change your codebase to better support minification?

Keep in mind that I do understand that in certain instances I need a variable assigned to `this` to reference outer scope inside a JavaScript closure. The use of `var me = this` I am taking about is solely for supporting minification.

Comment: What's wrong with the variable name `me`? What different solution would you expect?

Comment: @Bergi, it's not the variable name that's the problem, it is more that you have write code in a specific way that could be automated by tooling.

Comment: You want `var me = this;` to be inserted automatically by a tool in the appropriate places? How should they be recognized? And what does this have to do with minification, which is not a part of the code writing process?

Comment: Bergi, so the entire point, as I understand it, of me idiom is to ease the minification process, unless I am using it for closure scope (see above). If I wasn't concerned about minification I wouldn't assign a variable as a stand in for `this` in the first place.

Comment: Oh, I supposed you would only use that variable for the closure scope. I never would think of changing my code only to get better minification results.

Comment: @Bergi, if you make an answer describing why you don't use `me` and the magnification tools you use I could give you an upvote for your knowledge.

Comment: Actually I don't care about minification and use `me` variables only where I need to (closures - if I don't use `bind()`). Also I've never used a magnification tool (apart from autoindentation with some [js-beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) or inbuilt devtools). If you really want to give me upvotes, choose your favourite from [all my other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi?tab=answers) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not worry about minification until you are ready to deploy your code live. I would recommend using Google's closure compiler to minify all of your code once you are done. Check it out here: http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/

Comment: Interestingly the closure compiler seems to ignore `me` and just uses `this` everywhere. So the idiom doesn't make a difference if you are running your code through closure. Unless I am missing a flag somewhere.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question originally. I don't know of any minifiers which save a reference to `this` in a shorter than 4 character variable name in order to only reduce code size. It would have to detect if `this` was used more than once in the current scope, and then do that replacement.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't just support minification, it can also be used in closures. When you're creating functions, for example to use in a callback, you have to take care of what "this" is when the function is called. A common mistake when starting out in Javascript is to get the wrong 'this'. The "var me = this" pattern helps to avoid that. For example

```
function doSomething() {
    var me = this;
    callSomethingAsynchronous(42, function (result) {
        // Here 'this' will depend on the caller of the callback functon.
        me.theResult = result;
    });
}
```

Note that frameworks like Ext discourage this and have you pass the scope variable along with the callback.

```
callSomethingAsynchronous(42, me.handlerFunction, me);
```

It allows you do leave the definition of the handlerFunction on the prototype rather than keep creating them. Sometimes a closure is just the better way because you have to enclose information that is only known at runtime

```
function sayHelloInAContrivedWay (name) {
    getTheGreetingAsync(function (greeting) {
        console.log(greeting + name);
    });
}
```

I use "var me = this" whenever I'm accessing this more than once in a function. The minifier does reduce it to a single character. If I'm accessing a child object I'll create a var for that too

```
function keepInnerWombatFit () {
   var me = this,
       wombat = me.inner.wombat;

   wombat.run();
   wombat.jump();
   wombat.sitDown();

   me.excerciseCount++;
}
```

I've seen code with huge nested accesses typed out (or cut and pasted) again and again and again, which cannot be minified, may cost a little performance and is harder to read and maintain.

```
this.inner.wombat.run();
this.inner.wombat.jump();
this.inner.wombat.sitDown();
```