# Why does underscore use `root` instead of `this`?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In some cases, I see aliases to reduce the look-up chain, but in this case it is a simple one line alias with no reduction.

```
var root = this;
```

I think `this` is more descriptive as it will point to `window` in the browser or a multitude of different global variables if JavaScript is running on the server side.

If it had to be aliased I feel like

```
var global = this;
```

would be more descriptive.

Why is the word `root` used?  I've heard root used in the context of a "root user", but in the context of JavaScript development, I don't get it.

Comment: JS global scope is basically a tree. A tree has a root.

Comment: There is a comment directly above it that explains why. It is either referring to the window object or the exports object. Whenever 'new' is called, there would be a conflict with 'this', assigning it to a variable (root), avoids conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of `this` can change in closures.

```
function doSomething() {
    function helper() {
        alert(this); // I'm helping!
    }

    alert(this);
    helper();
}
someElement.onclick = doSomething;
```

While you might expect two alerts showing the same, the second one will actually refer to the global object instead (or `null` in strict mode, I think).

Doing `var root = this;` means that you have something that can reliably be called on, that won't change unexpectedly.

The name `root`... well, it's just a name.

Answer (score 1):

> In some cases, I see aliases to reduces the look-up chain, but in this case it is a simple one line alias with no reduction.

It has a little advantage in minification. `root` can be minified to a single letter, multiple uses of `this` cannot. See also [Is me = this in JavaScript a good practice to support minification?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14739306/1048572).

Also, the `root` variable is closed over in the [`_.noConflict`](http://underscorejs.org/#noConflict): function

```
_.noConflict = function() {
    root._ = previousUnderscore;
    return this;
};
```

Without `root`, it would need to be rewritten as

```
_.noConflict = function() {
    this._ = previousUnderscore;
    return _;
}.bind(this);
```

> If it had to be aliased I feel like `var global = this;` would be more descriptive. Why is the word root used?

Yeah, `global` would've been fine as well - only that it might add confusion since `global` *is* the idenfier used in Node for this object. `root` does stand for "root scope" or "root object" here.

Answer (score 0):

it uses root in the noConflict function

```
 _.noConflict = function() {
    root._ = previousUnderscore;
    return this;
  };
```

here `this` refers to **underscore** and root to the **global scope**.

as for root instead of global,it's a matter of opinion